# ROOT Library error

Tags: root-framework

So I installed Root 6.12.04 after I (unthinkingly) updated my OS to MacOS High Sierra. I cloned the git repository and followed all the steps on the "Quick Start" build root page. However something went wrong with my build and this is the error I get when I try to start a new instance of root and run Detector test:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN5TROOT14RegisterModuleEPKcPS1_S2_S1_S1_PFvvERKNSt3__16vectorINS5_4pairINS5_12basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEEiEENSB_ISE_EEEES2_
  Referenced from: /Users/MM/repos/nsd-rootscripts/compile/NSDRootScriptsLib.so
  Expected in: /Users/MM/cern/root-build/lib/libCore.so

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5TROOT14RegisterModuleEPKcPS1_S2_S1_S1_PFvvERKNSt3__16vectorINS5_4pairINS5_12basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEEiEENSB_ISE_EEEES2_
  Referenced from: /Users/MM/repos/nsd-rootscripts/compile/NSDRootScriptsLib.so
  Expected in: /Users/MM/cern/root-build/lib/libCore.so

Does anyone know where the build went wrong?

Comment: often turnout on [root-framework] questions here isn't great, consider asking on [https://root-forum.cern.ch/](https://root-forum.cern.ch/). That said, do I understand right the build and install of root itself went fine (i.e. without error message) and only when you run your code "Detector test" (your own writing or collaborateurs' tools…) you get that error? Did you have root installed on your old MacOS? If so, did you also rebuild that with your new version of root, or is that still the version compiled with your previous root version?

Answer (score 1):

This means that ROOT's dictionary interface has changed, but your dictionary sources (here: those in NSDRootScriptsLib.so) didn't get updated. Please re-generate the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but may start you on the right track.
If you demangle the symbol name you posted with `c++filt`, you get

```
TROOT::RegisterModule(
  char const*,
  char const**,
  char const**,
  char const*,
  char const*,
  void (*)(),
  std::__1::vector<
    std::__1::pair<
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
      int
    >,
    std::__1::allocator<
      std::__1::pair<
        std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
        int
      >
    >
  > const&,
  char const**
)
```

So, the problem is that your linker can't find the definition of this `TROOT::RegisterModule()` function.

You said the problem was with `libCore.so`. Looking at my `libCore.so` with

```
objdump -x libCore.so | grep RegisterModule | c++filt
```

I can see that I have an identical symbol defined. If this command doesn't print anything for you, then your compilation must have gone wrong and didn't compile this function into the library.

Unfortunately, this is as far as I can get you.